# Liferay projects building in wrong deploy folder

Tags: liferay

Working with liferay and portlets from last 3 weeks.

I downloaded the bundled liferay server and placed it on my local drive. 
I did the set up and was able to access localhost:8080 properly.

I also created some custom portlets and when build them in eclipse the war files were getting deployed in the path C:/liferay/deploy.

Now, I changed the server location, I wanted to have the server in D:/ drive. 
When I did the transition, started the tomcat server from D:/liferay/tomcat/bin/startup.bat
and then build the project, the war files are still building in c:/ drive.

When I copy the war file manually from c:/liferay/deploy to D:/liferay/deploy it gets deployed successfully. 
I want the war file to be created directly in the d:/liferay/deploy folder.
Can someone help me understand what all changes do i need to do here?

Comment: are you using liferay plugin sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Liferay plugin sdk then there would be file named as

`build.<userid>.properties`

in your plugin sdk.Change the below properties as per new configuration and  give a try

```
app.server.portal.dir
app.server.lib.portal.dir
app.server.lib.global.dir 
app.server.deploy.dir
auto.deploy.dir
```

Comment: I dont have the build.properties file in my eclipse project atleast, I am using liferay SDK. The only properties file i have in my project is  liferay-plugin-package.properties. Where to find this file just in case?

Comment: go to plugin sdk folder there it should be

Comment: Perfect! This worked. I am going through Portlets in Action. Never came across this file. If you can share documentation which you refer would be real help to me.

Comment: you can refer to "Liferay in Action" book